# Recursion countdown

Tags: python, recursion, data-structures

I'm working on this recursion function that takes in a number and counts down. So the first attempt gave me 0 followed by 'None' n times, my Second attempt threw a RecursionError:maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison.. please help, heres my code:

```
def count_down(n):
  if n <= 0:
    return n
  else:
    print(count_down(n-1))

print(count_down(10))

def count_down(n):
  if n <= 0:
    return n
  else:
    return(count_down(n) - 1)

print(count_down(10))
```

Comment: The first one needs to print and return in the else branch - the second one doesn't take away 1 before passing `n` back to the `count_down` function, so it never decreases.

Comment: @el-cc with the corrections mentioned above, you can adjust your code to either of these: https://repl.it/N7an/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work

```
def count_down(n):
    print(n)
    if n>0:
        count_down(n-1)
```

The only flaw is that from what I have tested, it doesn't like large numbers (over around 950). This is due to too much recursion, and cannot be fixed unless the code was made without recursion, like so:

```
def count_down(n):
    for i in range(n, 0, -1):
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is JavaScript code:

```
function countdown(n){

  if(n<1){
    return [];
  }else{
     var countArray = countdown(n-1);
     countArray.unshift(n);

    return countArray;
  }
}
console.log(countdown(10)); 

[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1] // array of recursion
```

Comment: Would you explain how countdown(n-1) is assigned to countArray, and then countArray is unshifted with n? This works, but I don't understand why. I see a function being put into a variable, not an array.

Comment: console.log(typeof countArray) logs 'object.' Is this because an array is not a primitive data type, but an object?

Comment: Does var countArray = countdown(n-1) mean: place a function where n is < 1 in countArray, and so countArray begins with []?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know If it is what you want but Try this:

```
def count_down(n):
    if n <= 0:
        return n
    else:
        print n
        return(count_down(n-1))

print(count_down(10))
> 10
> 9
> 8
> 7
> 6
> 5
> 4
> 3
> 2
> 1
> 0
```